# How to add data-webm-clickable in link_to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

I want to add `data-webm-clickable` in `link_to`

I tried

```
link_to(link_hash[:title],link_hash[:path].to_s, data: { webm-clickvalue: link_hash[:class]})

link_to(link_hash[:title],link_hash[:path].to_s, data: { webm: {clickvalue: link_hash[:class]}})
```

But none of them works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include dash inside a key in Hash, you can either: surround it by quotes or use underscore.

Try this:

```
<%= link_to @link_hash[:title], @link_hash[:path], data: { 'webm-clickvalue': @link_hash[:class] } %>
```

or this:

```
<%= link_to @link_hash[:title], @link_hash[:path], data: { webm_clickvalue': @link_hash[:class] } %>
```

Note that qoutes this will work with ruby > 2.1, and undescore with Rails >= 4